# Set User_id as key in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to the Firebase database.I have learned that push methods generate a unique key in Firebase database.My question is After the authentication, how to set the user_id as the key? so every time User logged in. User can manipulate its own data .. I have searched a lot but didn't find help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You usually save the user specific data under a node with the $user_id as key. You set write permissions to only that user. When the user first signs up, you create that node on the client side where the user just signed in and then populate with that user's data. So you first define the rule in the Firebase Console for that node ahead of time, create the user db node after first time authentication. From there, the user can only manipulate its own data. Check this doc for more on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: My question is how to implement user id as a key ?

Comment: You can save any key/value entry in a no sql database like Firebase real-time database. It is a JSON object. You just add something like {$user_id: $your_value} to a node and vary that depending on the data model you are using.